# Switch on Enum does not import class

Tags: java

Say I have an Enum as follows:

```
package stackoverflow.models;

public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2;
}
```

And then I have a POJO which has this Enum as one of its fields:

```
package stackoverflow.models;

public class MyPojo {
    private MyEnum myEnum;

    public MyEnum getMyEnum() {
        return myEnum;
    }

    public void setMyEnum(MyEnum myEnum) {
        this.myEnum = myEnum;
    }
}
```

Now, should I do a `switch` on `MyPojo.getMyEnum()`, I do **not** need to import the Enum directly into my class:

```
package stackoverflow.classes;

import stackoverflow.models.MyPojo;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
        switch(pojo.getMyEnum()) {
        case VALUE_1:
            break;
        case VALUE_2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I was just wondering why this is? How does Java resolve the Enum values if it doesn't import the Enum directly?

Comment: Well, it imports the enum indirectly since it is used by the `MyPojo` class (where no import is needed due to both being in the same package).

Comment: In this case, Enum is defined inside of another class (MyPojo), which behaves like static inner class. So answer to your question is: When you import your class, you also imported all it's inner classes and enums. If your enum was defined in separate file you would have to import it explicitly or use fully qualified name (e.g. org.mynamespace.MyEnum)

Comment: @Thomas I have never heard of indirect imports before. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @DoubleM `MyEnum` is defined in its own file, not a static inner class.

Comment: Well, if you import a class you basically tell the compiler which class you want to use. You don't have to do any imports at all if you always use the fully qualified class name like `new stackoverflow.models.MyPojo()`. That said the compiler knows how to import classes that are needed in a certain scope and since it knows that `MyPojo` uses `MyEnum` it will internally "import" that class as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not the enum type itself but the enum constants, where the scope include `case` labels of a `switch` statement, as mentioned in [this section of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The *scope* of a declaration is the region of the program within which the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a simple name, provided it is visible (§6.4.1).
>
> ...
>
> The scope of an enum constant C declared in an enum type T is the body of T, and any case label of a `switch` statement whose expression is of enum type T (§14.11).

Comment: Interesting its just the "simple name" that is needed. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The simple name is just the name of the enum constant. The key concept here is the scope of the declaration of this constant.